# Ubuntu installer attempts to mount an untargeted partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi, lvm

I have a machine with two disks. Both were LVM and encrypted. I wanted to install Kubuntu 20.04 on `/dev/sdb` and formatted it and created a GPT partition table and the necessary partitions. When I run the installer and set the partitions up for the installation I make sure that all partitions from `/dev/nvme0n` are set to "do not use". However, the installer keeps trying to mount `/dev/nvme0n1p1` which is the EPS of that drive. But it was set to "do not use". Luckily the mounting fails to due the encryption I think. Otherwise, the installer might possibly have overwritten my data on some of the `/dev/nvme0n1p1` partitions. Ok, what do I need to do to get the installer to not attempt mounting that partition so I can install the OS on `/dev/sdb`?

Here are some outputs and screenshots:

btw. clicking "Continue" does not help. The installation process is stuck at 33%.

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.75 GiB, 1858924544 bytes, 3630712 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB            
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6AF63064-BC79-4242-98B0-F2F47E638A21

Device           Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    2099199    2097152    1G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 2099200    3147775    1048576  512M Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p3 3147776 1953523711 1950375936  930G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 232.91 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 380EEC9B-8432-3048-B0AD-D19964B52D70

Device        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048   2099199   2097152     1G EFI System
/dev/sda2   2099200  18876415  16777216     8G Linux swap
/dev/sda3  18876416  20973567   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  20973568  99098623  78125056  37.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  99098624 488394751 389296128 185.6G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 57.31 GiB, 61530439680 bytes, 120176640 sectors
Disk model: Ultra           
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5a83b7c0

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          0   5162175   5162176  2.5G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       5123264   5131263      8000  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb3       5165056 120176639 115011584 54.9G 83 Linux
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0   1.7G  1 loop /rofs
sda           8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0     1G  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3        8:3    0     1G  0 part /target/boot
├─sda4        8:4    0  37.3G  0 part /target
└─sda5        8:5    0 185.6G  0 part 
sdb           8:16   1  57.3G  0 disk 
├─sdb1        8:17   1   2.5G  0 part /cdrom
├─sdb2        8:18   1   3.9M  0 part 
└─sdb3        8:19   1  54.9G  0 part /var/crash
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:4    0     1G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:5    0   512M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p3 259:6    0   930G  0 part
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like launchpad bug 1396379.  Disconnect the disk or make unavailable in firmware settings.

Comment: Thanks. Might indeed be that. Taking out the other drive of course solved it... even if it was a different reason.